# Delete elements from two nested arrays in one document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : "2646953848367646922",
    "arr1" : [
        {
            "n" : 1,
            "name" : "2646953848367646922"
        },
        {
            "n" : 0.75,
            "name" : "7750833069621794130"
        }
    ],
    "arr2" : [
        {
            "n" : 1,
            "name" : "2646953848367646922"
        },
        {
            "n" : 0.75,
            "name" : "7750833069621794130"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can I delete elements from two nested arrays by using only one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) for that.  In the shell:

```js
db.test.update({_id: "2646953848367646922"}, {$pull: {
    arr1: {name: "7750833069621794130"},
    arr2: {name: "2646953848367646922"}
}})
```